# Como autenticar uma conexão OAuth 2 com Postman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth2, postman

Minha API utiliza no backend Rails 5 a gem [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) ([omniauth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth)) para autenticação. O frontend está utilizando [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) (Angular 1.x).

Tenho todos os requests da API no [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Fiz a implementação de segurança e necessito autenticar o Postman a cada request. O devise_token_auth utiliza autenticação com OAuth 2 e estou tendo dificuldade de implementar essa autenticação.

[image]

Para esse tipo de autenticação, utilizando o Postman, qual o processo necessário para obter o acesso a API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de varias tentativas e erros, consegui efetivar o processo de autenticação em minha API e proceder com os acessos aos resources.

Abaixo detalho o procedimento. Qualquer duvida utilize os comentários abaixo.

## Postman

Em **Manage Environments** clique em **Bulk Edit** e adicione:

```
URL:https://sua.maravilhosa.api:3000
access-token:NOy64-MdaRd6UXMvm4OU3Q
client:gJ6tx2BKpmUVwQ5aQwtGiQ
expiry:1484612121
```

Crie uma request de autenticação, utilize a a URL `{{URL}}/auth/sign_in`, acesse a aba **Tests** e adicione:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access-token", responseHeaders['access-token']);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("client", responseHeaders['client']);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("expiry", responseHeaders['expiry']);
```

> Este código irá atualizar as variaveis **access-token**, **client** e **expiry**.

Crie (ou edite) uma request para sua API, acesse a aba **Headers**, clique em **Bulk Edit** e adicione:

```
access-token:{{access-token}}
token-type:Bearer
client:{{client}}
expiry:{{expiry}}
uid:atendente@juster.com.br
```

> Isso deve ser feito para cada request. Você irá encontrar mais detalhes sobre o cabeçalho de autenticação para devise_token_auth [clicando aqui](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#token-header-format).

## Rails

Para evitar ficar fazendo login a cada requisição, desabilite `change_headers_on_each_request`, para isso abra o arquivo `devise_token_auth.rb` e altere `config.change_headers_on_each_request` para `true`.

> Um novo recurso que adiciona a possibilidade de criar gatilhos com funções está sendo discutido [nessa issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/697). Isso poderia automatizar o processo e diminuir o esforço manual.

Feito os procedimentos acima basta clicar em **send** na aba do request.

## Bônus

Veja abaixo um gif animado demonstrando o processo.

[image: Explicação em detalhes]